# How to implement Search in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable

I want to have a feature with JTable wherein I'll provide a textfield to enter a value to be searched from the JTable and if this entered value matches with any of the cell values in the JTable then that particular cell should be highlighted & the cell font should be turned to BOLD. The values will be matched when the user presses Enter key after specifying the value in the text field.

How can I do this?

Comment: Great! So [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) And what problems are you having?

Comment: I didn't try anything, just i want to know if there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Yes, most of this is explained pretty well in the [JTable tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Have you gone through them yet?

Comment: You could search the model for the text of interest As for highlighting and bold, that's the job of the cell renderer.

Comment: yes i found a solution but it's so long, i search for a simple way. here is the code :http://www.coderanch.com/t/341354/GUI/java/Highlighting-JTable-cell-successful-search

Comment: The concepts in that example are what you're after. There is no quick and dirty 5 line solution. Sorry. You'll need to study the tutorial that I've linked to above and use the concepts contained as well as your example which on brief scan looks to be pretty good.

Comment: But in my mind, the key here is trying, experimenting, rolling up your sleeves and getting your hands dirty. Then if you're still stuck, you can come here with your code and a directly answerable question.

Comment: sorry i didn't see the link above, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at both links, and please come back if still stuck.

Comment: @jess-h If you feel like having *additional* question (to this), please feel free to post a new one, referencing the known Q&A's.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a way to resolve the problem. Here is the code:

```
public class JTableSearchAndHighlight extends JFrame {

   private JTextField searchField;
   private JTable table;
   private JPanel panel;
   private JScrollPane scroll;

   public JTableSearchAndHighlight() {

     initializeInventory();
   }

private void initializeInventory() {

    panel = new JPanel();

    searchField = new JTextField();

    panel.setLayout(null);

    final String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Surname", "Age"};

    final Object[][] data = {{"Jhon", "Java", "23"}, {"Stupid", "Stupido", "500"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Michael", "Winnie", "20"}, {"Winnie", "Thepoor", "23"},
                            {"Max", "Dumbass", "10"}, {"Melanie", "Martin", "500"},
                            {"Jollibe", "Mcdonalds", "15"}};

    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setBounds(0, 200, 900, 150);

    searchField.setBounds(10, 100, 150, 20);
    searchField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String value = searchField.getText();

            for (int row = 0; row <= table.getRowCount() - 1; row++) {

                for (int col = 0; col <= table.getColumnCount() - 1; col++) {

                    if (value.equals(table.getValueAt(row, col))) {

                        // this will automatically set the view of the scroll in the location of the value
                        table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(row, 0, true));

                        // this will automatically set the focus of the searched/selected row/value
                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);

                        for (int i = 0; i <= table.getColumnCount() - 1; i++) {

                            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new HighlightRenderer());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(searchField);
    panel.add(scroll);

    getContentPane().add(panel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Inventory Window");
    setSize(900, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class HighlightRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        // everything as usual
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // added behavior
        if(row == table.getSelectedRow()) {

            // this will customize that kind of border that will be use to highlight a row
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 1, 2, 1, Color.BLACK));
        }

        return this;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            new JTableSearchAndHighlight();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `JXTable` from the SwingX project has built-in support to search the table (look for the `Searchable` interface). It also allows to quickly create a search field which uses this `Searchable` interface: the `JXSearchField` and/or `JXSearchPanel`.

If I remember correctly this will cover most of your requirements. Probably only need to add some custom code for making the cell contents bold

Comment: Not sure who gave the down-vote. Up-voted to nullify it. This is a valid answer

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am also wondering what the reason is for the downvote. Always nice if the downvoter at least indicates in a comment why the down vote, allowing me to correct/improve my answer

Comment: +1 I think it's brilliant idea

Comment: How do I "link" the `JXSearchField` with the `JXTable`?